# Save resolution created with xrandr

Tags: fedora, xrandr

I am having troubles with my screen resolution on my fedora 24.

The screen keep getting 1024x768 and the 1280x1024 is unavailable.

digging a little i found, on arch linux forum, this commands:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=73738

```
gtf 1280 1024 60
xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  108.88  1280 1360 1496 1712  1024 1025 1028 1060  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-1 1280x1024_60.00
xrandr --output DVI-1 --mode 1280x1024_60.00
```

This solves my problem, but the new mode wont persists in a system reboot. Anyone knows how to force this config to me applied even after a system reboot?

Answer (score 1):

Download autorandr to your desktop and try it

For example, I have laptop with hdmi output and second screen:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --auto --left-of eDP-1-1
autorandr --save workstation1
autorandr --change
```

Where workstation1 is a custom setup to save. Any other name can be used, home, work, etc.

Or use arandr to save profile in file

Answer (score 0):

you can put the prefered resolution to a file like below:

Create a file in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/

40-monitor.conf

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier  "VGA1"
  Option      "PreferredMode" "1280x1024"
EndSection
```

Restart your X system.

If it doesn't work try creating the next two files in the same path, and restarting again:

30-graphic.conf

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier      "Intel Integrated"
    Driver          "intel"
EndSection
```

50-screen.conf

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "Default Screen"
    DefaultDepth  24
    SubSection "Display"
            Depth          24
            Modes         "1280x1024"  "1024x768"   "640x480"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Please read here for more details:

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/8301/how-do-i-change-my-monitors-resolution/

Comment: Oh, i will try this when i get home :)

Comment: Meh, it didnt. Fedora plain ignored the files